# getting Docker script to load with git-bash in ConEmu/Cmder

Tags: docker, boot2docker, git-bash, cmder

I see the shortcut to Docker on windows is:

```
C:\Program Files\Git\bin\bash.exe" --login -i "C:\Program Files\Docker Toolbox\start.sh"
```

I use `git-bash` in `Cmder/ConEmu`.

I want to execute this script when I start in that console, so I have all
my terminals in tabs contained in 1 program instead of git-bash here, docker
there.

I am having trouble finding the right way to get this .sh file to run. 
I find the quotes are different than running a new terminal window from
a windows shortcut.

I tried:

```
"C:\Program Files\Git\bin\bash.exe" --login -i "C:\Program Files\Docker Toolbox\start.sh""
```

returns:

> Either VirtualBox or Docker Machine are not installed. Please re-run the Toolbox Installer and try again.
>   Looks like something went wrong. Press any key to continue...

```
C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /c ""C:\Program Files\Git\bin\bash.exe" --login -i -- C:\Program Files\Docker Toolbox\start.sh"
```

returns:

> bash: C:\Program: No such file or directory

Current directory:

```
C:\Code\cmder_mini
```

Command to be executed:

```
"C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe" /c ""C:\Program Files\Git\bin\bash.exe" --login -i -- C:\Program Files\Docker Toolbox\start.sh"
```

> ConEmuC: Root process was alive less than 10 sec, ExitCode=127.
>   Press Enter or Esc to close console...

Comment: What have you tried and where exactly? Have you noted, that you have specified unbalanced double-quotes?

Comment: doh when I put my cursor into the 1st terminal to copy the error message it scrolled up and I saw the 'docker not found error' so I added to the task parameters the following switch /dir "C:\Program Files\Docker Toolbox"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A git `bash.exe` should inherit your %PATH% as $PATH

But the [docker toolbox Windows `start.sh`](https://github.com/docker/toolbox/blob/master/windows/start.sh#L6-L19) also depends on other environment variables which should be set *before* the call:

- `DOCKER_MACHINE`: `path/to/docker-machine.exe` (including the exe itself)
- `VBOX_INSTALL_PATH`: path to VirtualBox.

Make sure those are defined first, before calling ConEmu and calling your first command.

Comment: I got it working, I am not sure its the best way so I left this question open.

Comment: Basically I used the 1st command in the bottom textarea of a 'setup new Task' labeled 'Commands' with this: "C:\Program Files\Git\bin\bash.exe" --login -i "C:\Program Files\Docker Toolbox\start.sh"", then in the 2nd textbox labeled 'Task parameters' I put: '/dir "C:\Program Files\Docker Toolbox". Docker starts up but leaves me in %UserProfile% which is where the .docker is. The start.sh looks for ${VBOX_MSI_INSTALL_PATH}VBoxManage.exe.  Usually I use conemu task parameter to put me in c:\code

Comment: @magister OK. I would still advise to let go of docker toolbox: you don't need it.

Comment: ok how would I do that. it looks like I have to startup in the docker toolback directory so that start.sh will know where things are.  Could I run it from another folder?

Comment: @magister I just use docker-machine ssh: that brings me in the right shell session in the default VM.

Comment: Magister@NABU MINGW64 /c/Code
$ docker-machine ssh default   <!--works thanks, I feel more integrated already...  ;)

Comment: @magister great job! I often feel docker-machine is all I need.

Answer (score 4):

I found a really easy solution for me: just set the Cmder / ConEmu as the default terminal for console application. After that the Docker Quickstart Terminal opens Cmder/ConEmu directly instead of using the native Windows CMD. :)

You'll find the setting in Settings Dialog (Win+Alt+P or rightclick on the window header bar). Then go to:

Integration -> Default term

Check the checkbox for "Force ConEmu as default terminal for console applications" and press "Save settings".

Answer (score 1):

I found out a good solution to use docker normally in any cmder terminal I open.

Just paste this code in cmderRoot/config/user-profile.cmd

```
FOR /F "tokens=* USEBACKQ" %%F IN (`docker-machine status`) DO (
  SET machine_status=%%F
)


IF NOT %machine_status% == Running (
   cmd /c "docker-machine start default"
) 

FOR /F "tokens=*" %%i in ('docker-machine env') do @%%i
```